# Is it possible to make 1 layout and stretch it depending on the screen size?

Tags: swift, autolayout

As the title says:
Is it possible in xCode to make 1 view, lets say I make an app without auto layout just for the iPhone 5, and than stretch it depending on how big the screen size will get? The whole app is in landscape.

Comment: Yes, change the dimensions of the view during runtime. And arrange your subviews accordingly.

Comment: I like autolayout, it's very easy with it.

Comment: I have auto layout off. How can I change the views for each phone? I prefer doing that instead of auto layout...

Comment: I'm not sure on details, you should take many considerations: where to put the code? (ViewDidLoad? Or not), how to change the size? (Change the frame?), if you need call layoutIfNeeded() and more...

Comment: Why not use auto layout? It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

yes by using constraints

control drag from items (buttons , labels , uiimageview ) to your view and select your constraint

Comment: Without autolayout

Comment: yes by making the dimensions of the items programmatically  but i think constraints is a better choice

Comment: But he said he doesn't use and don't want to use autolayout

Comment: he won't use the constraints just making the width and hight according to the self view

Answer (score 0):

Place your view into your storyboard nicely, from edge to the edge, using e.g. iPhone 5 viewport size.

Then you may need to use something like this when autolayout turned off:

```
yourView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

// check whether you have not this property set to false, it should be set true as default
yourView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. What should I enter at "yourView"? My VC? That did not work. I tried view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight] and that did not work either. I uploaded a picture that explains maybe better what I want: http://nl.tinypic.com/r/11jazae/9

Comment: Sorry, you have posted 'Is it possible in xCode to make 1 view'. So for 1 view this could work like this. But if you don't want to use autolayout, I can't help you.